# ComboBox item selection with a single sendmessage

Tags: c++, winapi

Through code I am selecting comboxbox item from another process dialog

Here is the 2 route that have tried

```
// selecting using item text
void setComboBox(HWND hDlg, const char* value, int ctrlId) {
    SendDlgItemMessageA(hDlg, ctrlId, CB_SELECTSTRING, -1, (LPARAM) value);
    SendMessageA(hDlg, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(ctrlId,CBN_SELCHANGE),
            (LPARAM) GetDlgItem(hDlg, ctrlId));

}

 // selecting using item index
void setComboBox(HWND hDlg, int i, int ctrlId) {
    SendDlgItemMessageA(hDlg, ctrlId, CB_SETCURSEL, i, 0);
    SendMessageA(hDlg, WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(ctrlId,CBN_SELCHANGE),
            (LPARAM) GetDlgItem(hDlg, ctrlId));
}
```

So what i seen is in both the methods i need to send a second Message (WM_COMMAND), which is adding to latency.
 is there any ways to select and notify both using a single message ?

Comment: Automation would handle this for you

Comment: Thanks david, i am now considering to use UIA, btw how does the latency compares between my current 2 sendmessage based and uia, any idea pls.

Comment: This is your performance bottleneck?

Comment: Yeah, my only concern is to update forms in smallest possible time, so far it works on my machine consistently but i am open to uia if that gives more reliable results in a trade off to millisec delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  By design, changing the selection via code does not trigger `CBN_SELCHANGE`.  The documentation explicitly states this:

> The CBN_SELCHANGE notification code is not sent when the current selection is set using the CB_SETCURSEL message.

Only user actions trigger `CBN_SELCHANGE`, so you must send it manually.